# Bar Graph, chart.js PHP Will Not Load

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, chart.js

I have a bar graph that I'm attempting to create with chart.js that takes a PHP array and loads via ajax.  I am able to load the data with ajax (verified in the console) but I cannot get the data in the graph - here is the data in the console:

[image]

I have not received any error messages so I'm perplexed at this point.  Here is all of the code:

**HTML**

```
<?php
include 'connect.php';
?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>

</head>

<body>

</canvas><canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="javascript/charts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.6.0/Chart.min.js"></script>

</body>
```

**JS**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $.ajax({
  url: "prod_agg.php",
  method: "GET",
  success: function(data) {
   console.log(data);
   var date = [];
            var output = [];

   for(var i in data) {
    date.push(data[i].date);
    output.push(data[i].output);
   }

   var chartdata = {
    labels: date,
    datasets : [
     {
      label: 'Date',
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.75)',
      borderColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.75)',
      hoverBackgroundColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 1)',
      hoverBorderColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 1)',
      data: output
     }
    ]
   };

   var ctx = $("#myChart");

   var barGraph = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: chartdata
   });
  },
  error: function(data) {
   console.log(data);
  }
 });
});
```

I receive an empty graph:

[image]

Any help on this issue would be greatly valued!

Comment: do you know in what format, or exactly what the console data is supposed to look like>'

Comment: The photo of the Console output is the correct format as far as I can tell.  My guess is that the issue stems from attempting to push the values into the 'date' and 'output' arrays.

Answer (score 2):

The reason it's not working is because, you are getting the response data as a JSON string not JSON object.

So, to make it work with ChartJS, you need to parse it first, using `JSON.parse()` method ...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $.ajax({
      url: "prod_agg.php",
      method: "GET",
      success: function(data) {
         console.log(data);

         var data = JSON.parse(data);   //parse JSON string

         var date = [];
         var output = [];
         ...
```